# Move script.sh to bin

Tags: linux, bash, shell, path

I'm new to shell programming and I'm trying to create a simple script that gives me some infos on the status of the machine (i.e date, time, users logged in etc) on Scientific Linux 6 (I know it's old, but the department of my university runs on it so there's no escaping)

Basically I've created my script "sysinfo.sh"

```
 #!/bin/sh
  ....
  exit 0
```

as root user I want to move it so that I can be able to execute it anywhere and I thought the right way to do it was

```
sudo mv sysinfo.sh usr/local/bin
```

but I get the error message

```
mv: cannot move `sysinfo.sh' to `usr/local/bin': No such file or directory
```

then I looked for the PATH and it gives me

```
$ echo $PATH
/u/geo2/sw//System/tools/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

What is the right place to move my script?

Answer (score 3):

Best practice for these kind of manipulation or learning is to have scripts in your $HOME/bin directory.

```
mkdir $HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
mv sysinfo.sh $HOME/bin
chmod +x $HOME/bin/sysinfo.sh
```

If you anyway want to move it to /usr/local/bin, why not do that with:

```
sudo mv sysinfo.sh /usr/local/bin
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/sysinfo.sh
```

chmod command will make the script executable.

from chmod man:

> x -- The execute/search bits.

Comment: A better file name would be just `sysinfo` without the `.sh` extension, though.

Comment: sure, but assuming that the guy is learning, let him see, it is a shell file.

Answer (score 0):

The command that you posted indicates that you were trying to use the absolute path for copying, but you missed a leading slash --
the directory should be `/usr` instead of `usr`.

Try

```
sudo mv sysinfo.sh /usr/local/bin
```

Note that unless an absolute path is specified, the shell looks for the path relative to the current working directory.
In this case, the shell was looking for the subdirectory `usr` under the current directory which was not found;
hence the error message.

Comment: @tripleee, thanks for the edit! I could not figure out the correct way to post code. I am off to read the manual... :-)

Answer (score -1):

Thank you very much!
In the end, I didn't realize that the directory /usr/local/bin wasn't in the PATH
So i just needed to

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
sudo mv sysinfo.sh /usr/local/bin
```

:D

Comment: The second command in your post did the magic, not the first one. PATH variable is used by the shell only to look for executable files. `mv` and `cp` always expect source and destination to be provided. They can be either absolute paths or relative paths though.
Also, you have answered your own question, which is good. But the answer is not different from the ones already posted. You could simply accept one of the answers instead of posting a new one! SO is a Q&A site, works a bit different from the regular forums :-)

Comment: Additionally, now that you added the /usr/local/bin to your PATH variable and placed the script there, you can call that script for execution from anywhere while you are logged on